# kwargs why can't named "class"?

Tags: python

why can't named the "class" , How can i do , How not to modify def and dict under execution code.

```
>> someDict = {'class':'emacs','name':'python.py'}

>> def filterDicts(dict_list, **kwargs):
      for item in dict_list:
          if all(item[k] == v for k, v in kwargs.items()):
              yield item

>>filterDicts（someDict,class="emacs")
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    filterDicts(someDict,class="eamcs")
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Notice how the syntax highlighter highlights `class`? It's a keyword (reserved word).

Comment: You cannot use python 'reserved word' (keywords) as variable names or keys. Here is a list for your reference: https://docs.python.org/2.5/ref/keywords.html

Comment: Thank you, I know what to do